# How to prove that if (n,p,m) is Pythagorean triple then (n,p+n,k) is not?

Tags: number-theory

I know that this question is easy, but I actually experience some kind of intellectual eclipse and I can't find easy way of solving a described problem.
We know that: $n^2+p^2=m^2$ and $n^2+(p+n)^2=k^2$. Our purpose is easy way of proving that $k\notin \mathbb{Z}_+$ if $(n,p,m)\in \mathbb{Z}_+^3$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason why the following should have to be applied, but I also cannot think of any simpler way to resolve this question:

First, it is clear that if $(n,p+n,k)$ is not a reduced triple, then $(n,p)=(n,p+n)$ must be greater than $1$ and thus that $(n,p,m)$ is not a reduced triple, and it is not valuable to consider further as the factor can simply be divided out as usual.  So we consider $(n,p,m)$ and $(n,p+n,k)$ to be primitive triples.  Since both are primitive, this means that $m,k$ are both odd as well; $k$ can only be odd if $p$ is odd and $n$ is even (why?).

These triples look like this:

$$n^2+p^2=m^2\\
n^2+(p+n)^2=k^2=m^2+2np+n^2$$

Putting this together with Euclid's formulas for Pythagorean triples, we have:

$$\begin{align}
n&=2xy=2st\\
p&=x^2-y^2=s^2-t^2-2st\\
p+n&=2xy+x^2-y^2=s^2-t^2\\
m&=x^2+y^2\\
k&=s^2+t^2
\end{align}$$

Then we can consider quadratic residues.  The obvious modulus is $p$, so we have $n^2\equiv m^2\pmod p$ and also $n^2+(n+p)^2\equiv 2n^2\equiv k^2\pmod p$.  Since $(n,p)=1,\exists n^{-1}\pmod p$ and so $2\equiv (n^{-1})^2k^2\pmod p$ which means that $2$ is a quadratic residue$\mod p$ which is only possible if $p=8q\pm 1.$  One of $x,y$ is even and the other is odd; the odd one squares to $4u^2-4u+1$ which is $1$ plus a number divisible by $4$, but also $u^2-u$ is always even so the odd number squares to a number which is $8v+1$, so this means that when $p=x^2-y^2$ the even number must also have a minimum factor of $8$ in its square, which means that the even number must be divisible by $4$.  Then $n=2xy$ also has a minimum factor of $8$ and $x^2+y^2$ is of the form $8w+1$ and the same is true of $s^2+t^2$.  Therefore $8\mid k-m.$

Now we can say that $k=m+8a,k^2=(m+8a)^2=m^2+16a+64a^2=m^2+2np+n^2,$ which means that

$$64a^2+16a=2np+n^2 \tag 1\\
a={-16\pm\sqrt{16^2+4(2np+n^2)}\over 128}\\
={-8\pm\sqrt{64+2np+n^2}\over 64}$$

We must have positive $a$, so we take the positive branch.  Also, $n=8b$ since $8\mid n$ so we have

$$a={-1+\sqrt{b^2+2bp+1}\over 8}\tag 2$$

But in order for $a\in\Bbb Z^+$ we must have

$$\sqrt{b^2+2bp+1}=8r+1\implies b^2+2bp+1=64r^2+16r+1\implies 4\mid b$$

So now we have $b=4c\implies n=32c$.  Moving back to our equation $(1)$,

$$\begin{align}64a^2+16a&=2np+n^2\\
&=64cp+32^2c^2\\
\implies 4a^2+a&=4cp+64c^2
\end{align}$$

But now this means that $4\mid a$ or $a=4d$.  It appears that we have an infinite descent scenario, so now we check by going back to $(2)$ and making sure:

$$d={-1+\sqrt{16c^2+8cp+1}\over 32}$$

and once again we get that $d\in\Bbb Z^+$ requires $\sqrt{16c^2+8cp+1}=32f+1$ or $16c^2+8cp+1=32^2f^2+64f+1\implies 2c^2+cp=128f^2+8f\implies 8\mid c$.  Now $n=256g$ but the change is by a factor of $8$ instead of $4$, so we have to check again with $(1)$:

$$64a^2+16a=2np+n^2\\
32^2d^2+64d=512gp+256^2g^2\\
\implies 16d^2+d=8gp+32^2g^2$$

This is showing all the signs of infinite descent (now $8\mid d$ where previously $a=4d$...), which is untenable for positive integers.  Thus there can be no such Pythagorean triple $(n,p,m)$ where $(n,p+n,k)$ is also a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: @chubakueno: I hate this argument, but I have been unable to come up with anything better...

Answer (score 0):

Any pythagorean triple can be generated from two integers $x$ and $y$ (assuming $x>y$) using Euclid's formula. In particular there exist $x$ and $y$ such that:

$$n = x^2 - y^2$$
$$p = 2xy$$
$$m = x^2 + y^2$$

It is easy to see that $n^2 + p^2 = m^2$ in this case.

However, assuming that there exist integers $u>v$ such that:

$$n = u^2 - v^2$$
$$p = 2uv - n = 2uv - u^2 + v^2$$
$$k = u^2 + v^2$$

We get a contradiction:

$$n^2 + p^2 = (u^2 - v^2)^2 + (2uv - u^2 + v^2)^2 = 2u^4 - 4u^3v + 4uv^3 + 2v^4 \not= u^2 + v^2 = k^2$$

Comment: I'm not certain that it's entirely clear that $2u^4-4u^3v+4uv^3+2v^4\neq u^2+v^2$ for all $u,v.$  Perhaps some more exposition will help to verify this point.  Also, where did $p=2uv-n$ arise from?  Should it not have been written $p=2uv+n$ to match the question?

Comment: $p+n = 2uv$, hence $p = 2uv - n$.
I need to think about your first remark though.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha just gives me incredibly long calculations, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*x^4+-+4*x^3*y+%2B+4*x*y^3+%2B+2*y^4+%3D+x^2+%2B+y^2 but at least says the only integer solution is $x=y=0$.

Comment: Note that $x^2-y^2$,$2xy$,$x^2+y^2$ does not generate all nonprimitive triples; you need to include a constant factor.